Context needed to understand the meaning of a sentence
I know context is crucial. For instance

When she cooks dinner I will help her vs When she cooks dinner I will eat it.

One means I help during cooking and the other means that after cooking, I eat.
Does the same apply to verbs showing sudden actions such as scream?

When I was reading, she screamed and jumped: Is only one scream and one jump implied?

When I was performing on stage, people screamed and jumped: Does it imply multiple jumps and screams? And also, only one jump and scream is implied, as in my example 2



Hi. In your second example, the number of screams or jumps is not mentioned.   Why do you think it implies only one scream and jump?

Welcome to ELL. For your information, your sentence When she cooks dinner I will eat that is not idiomatic English.  The that seems odd, unless it is uttered as the speaker points to some item to indicate what they will eat when she cooks.

Where is your context?

@PaulTanenbaum Agreed, but changing "that" to "it" would make it fine, and that's clearly not the focus. Worth an edit maybe?

Yeah, @the-baby-is-you, its not being the focus is why I began with “for your information.” I agree that an edit is called for and I shall perform it.

When she cooks dinner, I will eat it can also mean that you enjoy her cooking, so that on any occasion when she is the cook you will be an eager diner.

You can't infer exactly how many screams and jumps there were.
The first example seems very odd, there's no connection between "reading" and "screaming", so perhaps people will start to imagine a back-story (to provide the missing context).  Perhaps she screamed because she saw a ghost, and was so afraid that she jumped to get away from it... so that would only be one scream and one jump.
But that's just my imagination! You don't say anything about ghosts and she might be repeatedly screaming and jumping all the time (many screams and many jumps)
People do scream and jump when some people perform.  The Beatles, for example. So again I start to imagine a story in which you are Paul McCartney...
But what you write doesn't imply that.
"While" might be better than "When".
Your first examples are not idiomatic, especially "When she cooks I will eat that".  That's not good English and doesn't have a common sense meaning.

What my example number 3 imply?

People do scream and jump when some people perform. The Beatles, for example. So again I start to imagine a story in which you are Paul McCartney (and there are many screams and jumps)...
But what you write doesn't imply that.

so what the difference " When I was performing on stage people were screaming and jumping" here it is sure that that both actions took the same amount of time  and my former example is more vague? Like we don"t know if they screamed the whole time or only a few times?

You are looking for more detail than exists.  You can't make up unnatural sentences out of context, and then ask how they would naturally be understood in context.,

Let's use the context you provided with The Beatles. Would there be any real difference between both examples?

"While I was performing the audience were screaming and jumping up and down." Using the progressive "were screaming" helps the sense that it was ongoing for the duration of the performance, and so must be repeated continuously.   It's nearly impossible to ask "what does the grammar alone imply".  You can't separate the grammar from the rest of the meaning.

yet in this context past simple works too with pretty much similar meaning, right?

Progressive the the better choice, for the reasons I explain above.

my verion with past simple also shows  that  screaming and jumoing was continuous or atleast repeated many times or not?

It's not given in the grammar.

sorry I know I ask to much. I  understnad it is not given by the grammar but  context would make it clear that people scream many times during the concert or is it rather wrong and I should use continuous?

@Artur This isn't really a question about English, it's a question about good writing: how much context the audience needs. While a lot can be inferred from context with the right shared knowledge, there is always the possibility of misunderstanding (even in cases where precise grammatical rules require one meaning, it may not be obvious what that meaning is), so it's good to give a bit more context than the absolute minimum, particularly if you can do it in an interesting way.
